# Why return doesn't work in NodeJS/Electron

Tags: node.js, electron

I have a problem with my NodeJS script.
Basically I want to add every file path to an array then display it in the bash console.
But when I try, it gives me `undefined`.

Here is my code:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

function repList(){
    var directoryPath = path.join('Q:/Programmes');
    let forbiddenDir = [".VERSIONS", "INSTALL"];
    fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) { //Scans the files in the directory
        if (err) {
            return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
        }
        else{
            files.forEach(function (file){ //Loops through each file
                var name = directoryPath+"/"+file;
                if(forbiddenDir.includes(file)){ //Don't accept the file if unvalid
                    console.log(`${file} is a forbidden name.`);
                }
                else{ //Filename is valid
                    fs.stat(name, (error, stats) => {
                        if (stats.isDirectory()) { //If directory...
                            tabRep.push(name); //... add the full filename path to the tabRep array
                        }
                        else if (error) {
                            console.error(error);
                        }
                    });
                };
            }); //End of loop
            return tabRep; //<-- THIS RETURN DOESN'T WORK
        }
    });
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    console.log(repList());
})
```

It gives me this output instead of `tabRep`'s elements:

> undefined 
> .VERSIONS is a forbidden name. 
> INSTALL is a forbidden name.

Inside the `Programmes` folder :

> \ Programmes
>
> > \ .VERSIONS 
> > \ Folder1 
> > \ File1 
> > \ Folder2 
> > \ INSTALL 
> > \ FolderN 
> > \ FileN

If anyone could give me some help, it would be really appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

`fs.readdir()` expects a callback function as second parameter (you passed that). The `return` you point at is the return of the callback function - not the return of the `repList()` function. Please read about async functions and callbacks in JavaScript to fully understand this concept, as this is very important in JavaScript. Also, your function `repList()` does not return anything! And declaration of variable `tabRep` is missing I think.

For so long, the the synchronous variant of `fs.readdirSync()`, like so:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

function repList(){
    var directoryPath = path.join('Q:/Programmes');
    let forbiddenDir = [".VERSIONS", "INSTALL"];
    const files = fs.readdirSync(directoryPath)
    const tabRep = []

    files.forEach(function (file){ //Loops through each file
        var name = directoryPath+"/"+file;
        if(forbiddenDir.includes(file)){ //Don't accept the file if unvalid
            console.log(`${file} is a forbidden name.`);
        }
        else{ //Filename is valid
            const stats = fs.statSync(name)
            if (stats.isDirectory()) { //If directory...
                tabRep.push(name); //... add the full filename path to the tabRep array
            }
        }
    }); //End of loop
    return tabRep; //<-- THIS RETURN DOES WORK NOW since now the function executes synchronously.
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly. I definitely need to seek further into the sync/async thing. Thanks again!